# When a bookmark's folder changes in firefox, which function of bookmark observer gets called?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

i've created an observer for `nav-bookmarks-service` the problem is, when the user changes the bookmark folder, `onItemChanged` or `onItemReplaced` dont seem to get triggered, so how should the bookmark folder add/change be noted by an extension/add-on?

Answer (score 0):

`onFolderChanged`

Notify this observer that a bookmark folder's information has changed. This will be called whenever any attributes like "title" are changed.

[MDN :: nsINavBookmarkObserver#onFolderChanged()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsINavBookmarkObserver#onFolderChanged%28%29)